# "спам" workspace.xml

Tags: github, webstorm

Решил воспользоваться благами, которые дает нам WebStorm. Подключил свой GitHub. WebStorm сразу же создал папочку .idea. Ну пусть с ним.
  Но в этой папке в том числе создается файл workspace.xml, содержимое которого автоматически обновляется каждые секунд 10. И тут же автоматически открывается десктопное приложение GitHub (да, да...), и хочет этот workspace.xml закоммитить. Работать !@#$% невозможно(
  Файл .gitignore с записью .idea присутствует.
 
  Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то настройки, которые заставят WebStorm успокоиться и не спамить изменения в workspace.xml?
 
  P.S. Работу с Git через консоль обязуюсь освоить.

Comment: Обычно пути к файлам IDE засовывают в файл `.gitignore`, чтобы git на них даже не смотрел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`workspace.xml` рекомендуется добавлять в `.gitignore` - см. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems. Но Вы, похоже, уже добавили этот файл в репозиторий, поэтому он присутствует в changelist - на добавленные файлы действие `.gitignore` не распространяется. Попробуйте удалить его из индекса:

```
git rm --cached workspace.xml
```

Comment: Спасибо, учитель!`
`Забавно, что применить команду
git rm --cached workspace.xml
не получилось, т.к. в консоли не находится папки .idea. Видимо из-за .gitignore.`
`Но принцип я понял. Удалил файл с жесткого диска и сделал 
git commit -a -m 'deleting files'
Помогло.